# Logitech K740 Replacement

Tags: keyboards

I'm looking for a substitute for the discontinued Logitech K740. I've bought several over the years for these reasons, and I'm looking for something comparable:

- Full-size US layout, 10-key, media keys
- Corded
- Key action - Logitech Perfectstroke

  - Good travel (not short)
  - Good tactility
  - Low force
  - Silent
- Low profile/tilt, palm rest (easy on wrists)
- Illumination

  - Key-cap letters lit in white
  - Nothing else (disablement is adequate)
- Durable, rigid
- Subdued color & design
- ~$100 USD

It's a shame Logitech discontinued the K740, but nothing good lasts I guess. I'm currently using a Logitech MX Keys, which is tolerable if not for needing two USB ports: one for the RF dongle and one for (indefinite) power. They don't sell a corded version, and they weren't clever enough to make it also function over the charging connector, so here I am looking for another make and model. Thanks for your recommendations!